# Android OnClickListener infinite button use problem

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to make an simple button that will cooperate with TextView, array and method changer (in public class Change). However the application uses the method changer only twice (below). It should work on every click. The changer method is used for the change in displayed array.

1-click: 1 |
2-click: 4 |
3-click: 1 |
4-click: 1 |
...-click: 1 |

I don't know where is the problem.

My target solution should be 1,4,1,4,1,4 ...

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String[] numbers =  {"1", "2","3","4"};
    private Button mButton;
    int i = 0;
    Change ch = new Change();
    TextView text;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        ch = new Change();

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                text.setText(numbers[0]);
                numbers = ch.changer(numbers);
                i++;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Change.java**

```
public class Change {

    String[] arraynew = new String[4];

    public String[] changer(String[] array){
        arraynew[0]=array[3];
        arraynew[1]=array[2];
        arraynew[2]=array[1];
        arraynew[3]=array[0];

        return arraynew;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arraynew variable in your code is global - so it will not create a new array every time you call the changer method, only rearranges its contents.

Here comes the tricky part: When you call the method for the second time, the parameter is the *same object* as arraynew. So when you do arraynew[0]=array[3] it changes 4 to 1 on the first slot; but arraynew[3]=array[0] will copy that newly changed 1 to the third index (where it is still the same 1 you put there). It basically eliminates the 4, making it impossible to recover.

Solution: Make arraynew local. If you declare it in the method, it will never be the same array, so the issue won't appear.

Comment: Wow, amazing, thanks a lot. It is working :)

Comment: If it works for you please accept and upvote the answer to help others who find this question.

Comment: Thanks for info. I have accepted the answer. Still  I don't have the privilege to upvote the answer.

Comment: No problem buddy. Welcome to Stack Overflow!